# OpenLayers 6 bad performance vectorlayer containing polygons and linestrings

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-6

The problem occurs when I'm displaying more than 2000 polygons and/or linestrings, the map's panning and zooming gets slow, also the loading of the osm tiles gets slow. The problem is gone when there are less features visible in the viewport(zooming in or panning away from features). I don't think it's an styling issue because it also occurs with the standard openlayers styling.

Because of the code snippet's limitations I could only add a few features of the real data to the map, unfortunately the problem isn't visible with this amount of data. But maybe someone can spot something wrong with the code or has a better way of displaying lots of polygons/linestrings on a vectorlayer.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 95vh;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.5.0/build/ol.js"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>My Map</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var geoJsonData = {
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "EPSG:28992"
        }
    },
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            685441.262918955,
                            7022605.59
                        ],
                        [
                            685441.039740355,
                            7022586.08
                        ],
                        [
                            685438.582036506,
                            7022584.54
                        ],
                        [
                            685436.865980189,
                            7022584.1
                        ],
                        [
                            685434.284371417,
                            7022583.44
                        ],
                        [
                            685434.261433221,
                            7022585.66
                        ],
                        [
                            685435.181676638,
                            7022586.01
                        ],
                        [
                            685436.736225901,
                            7022587.56
                        ],
                        [
                            685436.7100026,
                            7022588.07
                        ],
                        [
                            685436.571626044,
                            7022589.15
                        ],
                        [
                            685436.530014489,
                            7022589.94
                        ],
                        [
                            685436.323742369,
                            7022590.91
                        ],
                        [
                            685436.103124509,
                            7022592.1
                        ],
                        [
                            685435.779683307,
                            7022593.02
                        ],
                        [
                            685435.386742883,
                            7022593.68
                        ],
                        [
                            685435.074618194,
                            7022594.1
                        ],
                        [
                            685434.412768294,
                            7022594.54
                        ],
                        [
                            685433.80001363,
                            7022594.9
                        ],
                        [
                            685432.853304886,
                            7022595.19
                        ],
                        [
                            685431.872737418,
                            7022595.44
                        ],
                        [
                            685429.855558338,
                            7022595.36
                        ],
                        [
                            685429.073510219,
                            7022595.47
                        ],
                        [
                            685428.626841421,
                            7022595.77
                        ],
                        [
                            685428.399095635,
                            7022596.29
                        ],
                        [
                            685428.254838334,
                            7022596.83
                        ],
                        [
                            685428.115213326,
                            7022597.8
                        ],
                        [
                            685428.370541637,
                            7022654.54
                        ],
                        [
                            685428.382657063,
                            7022655.68
                        ],
                        [
                            685428.405020634,
                            7022656.21
                        ],
                        [
                            685428.376684955,
                            7022656.68
                        ],
                        [
                            685428.365367803,
                            7022657.18
                        ],
                        [
                            685428.005926213,
                            7022657.85
                        ],
                        [
                            685427.608527838,
                            7022658.09
                        ],
                        [
                            685425.602559711,
                            7022658.13
                        ],
                        [
                            685425.55793753,
                            7022664.88
                        ],
                        [
                            685426.897739616,
                            7022664.88
                        ],
                        [
                            685427.332560588,
                            7022665.02
                        ],
                        [
                            685427.605391799,
                            7022665.61
                        ],
                        [
                            685428.206939893,
                            7022901.65
                        ],
                        [
                            685425.646257605,
                            7022901.4
                        ],
                        [
                            685425.73507516,
                            7022909.73
                        ],
                        [
                            685428.225456642,
                            7022909.64
                        ],
                        [
                            685428.78013709,
                            7022910.08
                        ],
                        [
                            685428.937050443,
                            7022910.73
                        ],
                        [
                            685428.103531107,
                            7022956.32
                        ],
                        [
                            685441.139919701,
                            7022956.91
                        ],
                        [
                            685441.139394247,
                            7022956.39
                        ],
                        [
                            685441.523807046,
                            7022936.19
                        ],
                        [
                            685441.875336024,
                            7022920.72
                        ],
                        [
                            685441.748992747,
                            7022902.63
                        ],
                        [
                            685441.799700934,
                            7022887.07
                        ],
                        [
                            685441.678791454,
                            7022874.18
                        ],
                        [
                            685441.678177743,
                            7022853.82
                        ],
                        [
                            685441.695029443,
                            7022831.97
                        ],
                        [
                            685441.799738679,
                            7022808.98
                        ],
                        [
                            685441.509185026,
                            7022780.18
                        ],
                        [
                            685441.507866647,
                            7022747.26
                        ],
                        [
                            685441.511628204,
                            7022713.25
                        ],
                        [
                            685441.428954069,
                            7022689.88
                        ],
                        [
                            685441.289877033,
                            7022669.03
                        ],
                        [
                            685441.130931211,
                            7022647.89
                        ],
                        [
                            685441.138783873,
                            7022629.88
                        ],
                        [
                            685441.262918955,
                            7022605.59
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            685444.18869203,
                            7022248.82
                        ],
                        [
                            685441.789495138,
                            7022246.66
                        ],
                        [
                            685437.679498426,
                            7022246.43
                        ],
                        [
                            685437.60881564,
                            7022247.46
                        ],
                        [
                            685437.875308075,
                            7022247.45
                        ],
                        [
                            685438.308503048,
                            7022247.44
                        ],
                        [
                            685438.708375331,
                            7022247.44
                        ],
                        [
                            685439.242607448,
                            7022247.53
                        ],
                        [
                            685439.316379993,
                            7022248.2
                        ],
                        [
                            685439.3274271,
                            7022249.23
                        ],
                        [
                            685439.127222011,
                            7022250.77
                        ],
                        [
                            685438.707830507,
                            7022256.76
                        ],
                        [
                            685437.974723061,
                            7022263.01
                        ],
                        [
                            685437.591056324,
                            7022270.78
                        ],
                        [
                            685437.007543071,
                            7022277
                        ],
                        [
                            685436.713774353,
                            7022285.39
                        ],
                        [
                            685436.499661796,
                            7022291.88
                        ],
                        [
                            685436.116170517,
                            7022299.66
                        ],
                        [
                            685436.065799784,
                            7022301.97
                        ],
                        [
                            685435.925219719,
                            7022308.32
                        ],
                        [
                            685435.562847544,
                            7022313.4
                        ],
                        [
                            685435.623426476,
                            7022319.08
                        ],
                        [
                            685435.462060736,
                            7022324.26
                        ],
                        [
                            685435.363777394,
                            7022329.1
                        ],
                        [
                            685435.418924352,
                            7022332.71
                        ],
                        [
                            685435.653602019,
                            7022339.09
                        ],
                        [
                            685435.737165769,
                            7022346.92
                        ],
                        [
                            685435.694194389,
                            7022364.76
                        ],
                        [
                            685435.652735202,
                            7022384.31
                        ],
                        [
                            685435.738598215,
                            7022404.85
                        ],
                        [
                            685436.174618787,
                            7022430.1
                        ],
                        [
                            685436.565281653,
                            7022462.04
                        ],
                        [
                            685436.303682025,
                            7022462.51
                        ],
                        [
                            685435.811668127,
                            7022463.25
                        ],
                        [
                            685435.548821173,
                            7022463.6
                        ],
                        [
                            685435.017960082,
                            7022463.82
                        ],
                        [
                            685434.52042255,
                            7022464.05
                        ],
                        [
                            685433.922023352,
                            7022464.19
                        ],
                        [
                            685433.322555095,
                            7022464.23
                        ],
                        [
                            685432.32320376,
                            7022464.27
                        ],
                        [
                            685431.523437613,
                            7022464.28
                        ],
                        [
                            685430.75548063,
                            7022464.14
                        ],
                        [
                            685430.756104216,
                            7022464.2
                        ],
                        [
                            685430.30406814,
                            7022465.41
                        ],
                        [
                            685434.412778199,
                            7022465.36
                        ],
                        [
                            685434.802664246,
                            7022465.35
                        ],
                        [
                            685440.96330826,
                            7022461.77
                        ],
                        [
                            685440.944375385,
                            7022448.44
                        ],
                        [
                            685440.744843742,
                            7022391.78
                        ],
                        [
                            685440.542264941,
                            7022350.61
                        ],
                        [
                            685440.607276516,
                            7022344.83
                        ],
                        [
                            685440.617500947,
                            7022339.08
                        ],
                        [
                            685440.514106814,
                            7022332.66
                        ],
                        [
                            685440.476373562,
                            7022321.94
                        ],
                        [
                            685443.22555292,
                            7022277.4
                        ],
                        [
                            685444.038219756,
                            7022256.58
                        ],
                        [
                            685444.06842619,
                            7022251.61
                        ],
                        [
                            685444.18869203,
                            7022248.82
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            683165.662570441,
                            7015140
                        ],
                        [
                            683159.556028829,
                            7015136.33
                        ],
                        [
                            683153.814366729,
                            7015132.68
                        ],
                        [
                            683148.441811934,
                            7015129.3
                        ],
                        [
                            683105.779833152,
                            7015101.19
                        ],
                        [
                            683093.267616621,
                            7015092.59
                        ],
                        [
                            683045.441787788,
                            7015058.55
                        ],
                        [
                            683038.326329378,
                            7015053.26
                        ],
                        [
                            682987.278433276,
                            7015015.57
                        ],
                        [
                            682986.479404425,
                            7015015.58
                        ],
                        [
                            682985.814065691,
                            7015015.64
                        ],
                        [
                            682984.967863592,
                            7015015.91
                        ],
                        [
                            682984.203856349,
                            7015016.09
                        ],
                        [
                            682983.146609611,
                            7015016.88
                        ],
                        [
                            682982.008896435,
                            7015017.95
                        ],
                        [
                            682980.774761716,
                            7015019.34
                        ],
                        [
                            682979.626278948,
                            7015020.98
                        ],
                        [
                            682979.056964096,
                            7015022.27
                        ],
                        [
                            682996.353278818,
                            7015035
                        ],
                        [
                            683004.203313017,
                            7015040.66
                        ],
                        [
                            683078.560699547,
                            7015094.55
                        ],
                        [
                            683104.80319641,
                            7015112.96
                        ],
                        [
                            683127.116142841,
                            7015127.47
                        ],
                        [
                            683151.031686673,
                            7015142.39
                        ],
                        [
                            683171.566943387,
                            7015154.99
                        ],
                        [
                            683188.691917144,
                            7015164.96
                        ],
                        [
                            683204.651059709,
                            7015173.28
                        ],
                        [
                            683229.647312627,
                            7015186.75
                        ],
                        [
                            683253.803814151,
                            7015198.7
                        ],
                        [
                            683256.589226861,
                            7015193.27
                        ],
                        [
                            683255.109922996,
                            7015188.86
                        ],
                        [
                            683254.512580149,
                            7015188.57
                        ],
                        [
                            683240.266187512,
                            7015181.18
                        ],
                        [
                            683226.541141671,
                            7015173.97
                        ],
                        [
                            683214.07242753,
                            7015167.34
                        ],
                        [
                            683201.799055975,
                            7015160.61
                        ],
                        [
                            683171.278563805,
                            7015143.25
                        ],
                        [
                            683165.662570441,
                            7015140
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            684660.95933256,
                            7015711.04
                        ],
                        [
                            684666.608045845,
                            7015714.3
                        ],
                        [
                            684669.26033297,
                            7015707.52
                        ],
                        [
                            684670.215927562,
                            7015704.36
                        ],
                        [
                            684666.845479509,
                            7015704.63
                        ],
                        [
                            684663.977347483,
                            7015705
                        ],
                        [
                            684662.697910324,
                            7015707.45
                        ],
                        [
                            684660.95933256,
                            7015711.04
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            682431.836984001,
                            7012425.64
                        ],
                        [
                            682434.633878801,
                            7012426.86
                        ],
                        [
                            682463.295256523,
                            7012440.03
                        ],
                        [
                            682480.651505168,
                            7012449.02
                        ],
                        [
                            682507.099398825,
                            7012462.01
                        ],
                        [
                            682524.597749389,
                            7012470.4
                        ],
                        [
                            682547.925858517,
                            7012481.36
                        ],
                        [
                            682559.251616914,
                            7012487.35
                        ],
                        [
                            682571.561922136,
                            7012494.24
                        ],
                        [
                            682590.325470721,
                            7012503.31
                        ],
                        [
                            682602.510595235,
                            7012509.19
                        ],
                        [
                            682621.087917921,
                            7012517.13
                        ],
                        [
                            682623.782350992,
                            7012518.42
                        ],
                        [
                            682624.996075483,
                            7012517.01
                        ],
                        [
                            682623.449307545,
                            7012516.3
                        ],
                        [
                            682613.387180935,
                            7012511.97
                        ],
                        [
                            682601.016930779,
                            7012506.05
                        ],
                        [
                            682587.141936656,
                            7012498.81
                        ],
                        [
                            682571.003352629,
                            7012490.27
                        ],
                        [
                            682557.337232595,
                            7012483.76
                        ],
                        [
                            682547.793982125,
                            7012478.9
                        ],
                        [
                            682542.430572947,
                            7012476.21
                        ],
                        [
                            682543.956786679,
                            7012473.31
                        ],
                        [
                            682536.684620611,
                            7012469.67
                        ],
                        [
                            682535.225261859,
                            7012472.6
                        ],
                        [
                            682530.040866919,
                            7012470
                        ],
                        [
                            682515.165440386,
                            7012463.06
                        ],
                        [
                            682495.26944715,
                            7012453.1
                        ],
                        [
                            682479.821651433,
                            7012445.36
                        ],
                        [
                            682459.928235473,
                            7012435.65
                        ],
                        [
                            682446.418342533,
                            7012428.61
                        ],
                        [
                            682430.377348588,
                            7012421.76
                        ],
                        [
                            682428.527227827,
                            7012420.03
                        ],
                        [
                            682428.740911885,
                            7012418.64
                        ],
                        [
                            682426.296639922,
                            7012417.4
                        ],
                        [
                            682426.839445803,
                            7012420.18
                        ],
                        [
                            682429.029804245,
                            7012422.78
                        ],
                        [
                            682431.836984001,
                            7012425.64
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

      
      var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
          features: new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(JSON.stringify(geoJsonData)),
        })
      });
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          }),
          vectorLayer
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [vectorLayer.getSource().getExtent()[0], vectorLayer.getSource().getExtent()[1]],
          zoom: 13
        })
      });
      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by using a VectorImageLayer, seems to be a lot faster than a normal VectorLayer

Answer (score 0):

You should use tilelayer for massive data. If you don't have geoserver or etc, [geojsonvt plugin](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geojson-vt.html) create on-the-fly tile. GeojsonVT can easily render 150k+ features which have lots of attribute value.